# How to map two columns of two files and ouput the NA if not found?

Tags: pandas, bash

I want to map two columns of two files and extract common with all values in the third file and return "NA" in the third column if not found

file 1

```
a1  6461480
b2  6470742
c1  9607765
bj  12775725
kd  12893249
m3  12920302
fg  13318448
kd  13319564
jk  13371119
```

file2

```
a1  6461480 0.01
b2  6470742 0.02
c1  9607765 0.001
bj  12775725    0.36
jd  12345675    0.23
zk  12348906    0982
kd  12893249    0.02
m3  12920302    0.05
```

expected ouput:

```
a1  6461480 0.01
b2  6470742 0.02
c1  9607765 0.001
bj  12775725    0.36
kd  12893249    0.02
m3  12920302    0.05
fg  13318448    NA
kd  13319564    NA
jk  13371119    NA
```

I tried following code but ouput is only mapped terms and its value

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' file2 file1
```

Is to possible to do in python pandas ?

Comment: use ```pandas merge```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# import pandas 
import pandas as pd 

# read data data 
df1 = pd.read_table('file1', sep="\t") 
df2 = pd.read_table('file2',sep="\t") 

mapped = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='Name', how ='left') 
mapped 


a1  6461480 0.01
b2  6470742 0.02
c1  9607765 0.001
bj  12775725    0.36
kd  12893249    0.02
m3  12920302    0.05
fg  13318448    NA
kd  13319564    NA
jk  13371119    NA
```